# Read a XML file and print the tags using C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

There is a XML file and I have to identify, store and print the Unique tags present in it.

Example XML File:

```xml
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I need to store note,to,from,heading,body etc.. tags in an array and print them afterwards.

Below is the code I tried, but facing issue while checking and removing `/` from the closing tag to identify duplicate tags.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Max number of characters to be read/write from file*/
#define MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION 1000000 

int read_and_show_the_file()
{  
   FILE *fp;
   char text[MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION];
   int i;

   fp = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "r");

  if(fp == NULL)
   {
      printf("File Pointer is invalid\n");
      return -1;
   }
   //Ensure array write starts from beginning
   i = 0;

   //Read over file contents until either EOF is reached or maximum     characters is read and store in character array
   while( (fgets(&text[i++],sizeof(char)+1,fp) != NULL) && (i<MAX_CHAR_FOR_FILE_OPERATION) ) ; 
   const char *p1, *p2, *temp;
   temp = text;

   while(p2 != strrchr(text, ">"))
   {
       p1 = strstr(temp, "<");
       p2 = strstr(p1, ">");
       size_t len = p2-p1;
       char *res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len));
       strncpy(res, p1+1, len-1);
       res[len] = '\0';
       printf("'%s'\n", res);

       temp = p2 + 1;
   }

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}

main()
{
   if( (read_and_show_the_file()) == 0)
   {
      printf("File Read and Print is successful\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I also tried the strcmp to check the value of `if(strcmp(res[0],"/")==0)` to check the closing tag, but not working, showing segmentation fault. No example is present on C. Please review and suggest.

Below is the output:

```
'note'
'to'
'/to'   //(Want to remove these closing tags from output)
'from'
'/from' //(Want to remove these closing tags from output)
 and so on..
```

Segmentation fault also occurring.

Comment: Regarding the `strcmp` issue, first of all it should have the compiler shout a warning at you for not using the correct types. And that's the reason for the crash, you try to compare a *single character* with a string.

Comment: Also note that `res[len]` is *out of bounds*, and leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Lastly please read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

This addresses just one of the segmentation faults in your question:

You have to give string to strcmp, you can not just give character (`res[0]`). But since you don't need to compare string, why don't you just compare the first character `(res[0]=='/')`?